# Error: Statement 'BACKUP DATABASE' in not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, backup

While writing this question on this site, many similar questions were suggested on the same topic by others, but I did not find the desired answer.
I'm trying to write code in WPF C# to create a database management application
But the following statement does not work with SQL:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = 'C:\\databases\\MyTestData-21-07-2022.bak';
```

The SQL version I'm working on is:

Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 12 2022 23:11:24   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation.

I got it through the following statement: "SELECT @@VERSION"

Can anyone give me a unique solution?
Or is this not possible at all?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As far as I can see Azure SQL has a different syntax(TO URL) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current&preserve-view=true

Comment: Are you using an Azure SQL Database, by any chance? You can't do a `BACKUP` in the same way on an Azure SQL Database; the backups are done automatically in the cloud. Alternatively, you could create a BACPAC (via ADS for example).

Comment: Tag your question with the type of Azure database you are using (`azure-sql-database` or `azure-sql-managed_instance`). The answer will vary accordingly.

Comment: @Larnu yes, I'm using Azure SQL Database

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, you don't `BACKUP` your database. You manage the backups in your Azure Portal, or (as I also mentioned) you can [download a BACPAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql).

Comment: Why have you now tagged *both* [[tag:azure-sql-database]] and [[tag:azure-sql-managed_instance]]? These are **not** the same thing... Which is it, an Azure SQL Database or an Azure SQL Managed Instance? The version number *suggests* the former.

Comment: @Larnu excuse me, I misunderstood about the tag

Comment: @Sergey I used the statement in the link, but it still gives me the same error.
I have downloaded and installed the latest version of SQL Server but when I write the following statement: SELECT @@Version
It still gives me the same old version.
Where can I update the intended version?

Comment: @Khalid, Azure SQL Database does not support the `BACKUP` T-SQL command. See @Larnu's comments for alternatives. I think you need a deeper understanding of the various SQL Server platforms if your goal is to write a database management application that supports all of them.

Comment: @DanGuzman excuse me for asking, but I'm really a beginner in this field and I can't understand all the suggestions, especially the ones that are just shortcuts.
I read Larnu's comment and copied and pasted his suggestion into google but no specific result.
Please, is it possible to support your suggestions with some links, or to write full phrases and not abbreviations?

Comment: @Khalid, did you read the documentation? Here is the link again for your convenience: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use BACKUP DATABASE or BACKUP LOG on Azure SQL Database. Native SQL Server backups are not possible on Azure SQL. Instead of Native SQL Server Backups you create bacpacs, and you can save bacpacs to a local drive on your computer or to an Azure Storage account.

On this documentation you will find how to create a bacpac of your database and save it to an Azure Storage Account. You can later download that bacpac (backup) to your local computer using Azure Storage Explorer if you want. Below and example of how to create a bacpac using PowerShell and save it to Azure Storage.

```
$exportRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
```

You can also create a bacpac of your Azure SQL Database and save it to your local F: drive using sqlpackage tool

```
SqlPackage /Action:Export /SourceServerName:SampleSQLServer.sample.net,1433

/SourceDatabaseName:SampleDatabase /TargetFile:"F:\Temp\SampleDatabase.bacpac"
```

Comment: You are always welcome!